# Calculating days of therapy in a sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm attempting to calculate days of therapy by month from an oracle database. The (vastly simplified) data is as follows:

```
 Therapies                          
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| Rx Number | StartDate | StopDate |
|-----------+-----------+----------|
| 1         | 12-29-14  | 1-10-15  |
| 2         | 1-2-15    | 1-14-15  |
| 3         | 1-29-15   | 2-15-15  |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

For the purposes of this example, all times are assumed to be midnight. The total days of therapy in this table is (10-1 + 32-29) + (14-2) + (15-1 + 32-29) = 41. The total days of therapy in January in this table is (10-1) + (14-2) + (32-29) = 24.

If I wanted to calculate days of therapy for the month of January , my best effort is the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(stopdate - startdate) 
FROM therapies 
WHERE startdate > to_date('01-JAN-15') 
  AND stopdate < to_date ('01-FEB-15');
```

However, rx's 1 and 3 are not captured at all. I could try the following instead:

```
SELECT SUM(stopdate - startdate) 
FROM therapies 
WHERE stopdate > to_date('01-JAN-15') 
  AND startdate < to_date ('01-FEB-15');
```

But that would include the full duration of the first and third therapies, not just the portion in January. To make the matter more complex, I need these monthly summaries over a period of two years. So my questions are:

1. How do I include overhanging therapies such that only the portion within the target time period is included, and
2. How do I automatically generate these monthly summaries over a two year period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I include overhanging therapies such that only the portion
>   within the target time period is included?

```
select sum(
    greatest(least(stopdate, date '2015-01-31' + 1) 
      - greatest(startdate, date '2015-01-01'), 0)) suma
  from therapies
```

> How do I automatically generate these monthly summaries over a two
>   year period?

```
with period as (select date '2014-01-01' d1, date '2015-12-31' d2 from dual),
months as (select trunc(add_months(d1, level-1), 'Month') dt 
    from period connect by add_months(d1, level-1)<d2)
select to_char(dt, 'yyyy-mm') mth, 
    sum(greatest(least(stopdate, add_months(dt, 1)) - greatest(startdate, dt), 0)) suma
  from therapies, months
  group by to_char(dt, 'yyyy-mm') order by mth
```

Above queries produced desired output. Please insert your dates in proper places to change analyzed periods.
In second SQL inner subquery `months` gives 24 dates, one for each month. The rest is only maneuvering 
with functions `greatest()`,`least()` and some math.

Answer (score 1):

Use a case statement to set the start date and stop date. Like the below:

`select sum(
  Stopdate -
  (case Startdate
    when startdate < to_date(@YourBeginingDate) then To_date(@YourBeginingDate)
    else startdate 
  end)
FROM therapies 
WHERE stopdate > to_date(@YourBeginingDate) 
  AND StartDate < to_date(@YourEndingDate)`

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like the following:

```
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT 1 AS rx, DATE'2014-12-29' AS start_date
       , DATE'2015-01-10' AS stop_date
    FROM dual
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE'2015-01-02', DATE'2015-01-14'
    FROM dual
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, DATE'2015-01-29', DATE'2015-02-15'
    FROM dual
)
SELECT TRUNC(rx_dt, 'MONTH') AS rx_month, SUM(rx_cnt) AS rx_day_cnt
  FROM (
    SELECT rx_dt, COUNT(*) AS rx_cnt
      FROM (
        SELECT rx, start_date + LEVEL - 1 AS rx_dt
          FROM t1
       CONNECT BY start_date + LEVEL - 1 < stop_date
           AND PRIOR rx = rx
           AND PRIOR DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE IS NOT NULL
    ) GROUP BY rx_dt
) GROUP BY TRUNC(rx_dt, 'MONTH')
 ORDER BY rx_month
```

Results:

```
12/1/2014 12:00:00 AM   2
1/1/2015 12:00:00 AM    24
2/1/2015 12:00:00 AM    15
```

[**See SQL Fiddle here.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb/1879)

What I am doing is using `LEVEL` and `CONNECT BY` to get all the days of therapy based on `start_date` and `stop_date` (not inclusive). I then `GROUP BY` the therapy date (`rx_dt`) to handle the overlapping therapies. Then I `GROUP BY` the *month* of the therapy using the `TRUNC()` function.

This should work just fine over a two-year period (or more); just add that filter before the last `GROUP BY`:

```
WHERE rx_dt >= DATE'2014-01-01'
  AND rx_dt < DATE'2016-01-01'
GROUP BY TRUNC(rx_dt, 'MONTH')
```

Note that if your primary key is composite, you should include all the columns in the `CONNECT BY` clause:

```
CONNECT BY start_date + LEVEL - 1 < stop_date
    AND PRIOR rx = rx
    AND PRIOR patient_id = patient_id
    --etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky, as you need to capture days from sessions that:

- Begin before the month and end after the month
- Begin before the month and end during the month
- Begin during the month and end after the month
- Begin during the month and end during the month

To get those sessions, you can use a WHERE statement like this (the @ symbol means that those are variables being passed in):

***examples are in TSQL, PLSQL might have somewhat different syntax**

```
WHERE startdate < @endDate AND stopdate > @startDate
```

That should capture all four of those scenarios that I listed.

Then you only need to capture days that occurred during the month.  I do this with a query that replaces the startdate/enddate with the date range limits if they exceed the range, like this:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN enddate > @endDate then @endDate ELSE enddate END -
  CASE WHEN startdate < @startDate THEN @startDate ELSE startdate END
```

So your whole query should look like this:

```
SELECT
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN enddate > @endDate then @endDate ELSE enddate END -
    CASE WHEN startdate < @startDate THEN @startDate ELSE startdate END
  )
FROM therapies 
WHERE startdate < @endDate AND stopdate > @startDate
```

If you want to run that for two years, toss that code in a function that accepts @startDate and @endDate parameters, then call it from a query that gives you two years worth of months, like this:

```
WITH dateCTE AS (
  SELECT 
    GETDATE() AS StartDate,
    DATEADD(Month, 1, GETDATE()) AS EndDate

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        DATEADD(MONTH, -1, StartDate),
        DATEADD(MONTH, -1, EndDate)
    FROM dateCTE
    WHERE StartDate > DATEADD(YEAR, -2, GETDATE())
)

SELECT 
    StartDate, 
    EndDate,
    SomeFunction(StartDate, EndDate)
FROM dateCTE
```

Comment: DATEADD isn't an Oracle function; you'd need to use add_months(). Plus the recursive with clause with dates doesn't always work in some versions of Oracle, due to a bug. You'd have to use a connect by query in that case.

Comment: Yeah, I specified that it was TSQL.  I figured there some equivalent in PLSQL that he could use.  I'm not familiar enough with it to know.